# Google Accounts OAuth2 Support framework?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-oauth

Is there an existing framework for using the Google Accounts OAuth2 Authentication process (described [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp?hl=fr#libraries) for Objective-C/iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called the Google Toolbox for Mac, GTM. It also has iOS components.

https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/